# Retrieving just one value from a Record in CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm learning to use CloudKit and finally managed to retrieve/query data hard coded into the dashboard. I'm trying to query only one value from a record using a `CKQueryOperation` but I always receive all the values in each and every record.
In my code below I'm trying to get just the "age" values by using the `desiredKey` property - what I get back is "age", "firstName", "lastName" etc etc.

```
let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase

// select all records
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "quizRecord", predicate: predicate)

// get just one value only
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.desiredKeys = ["age"]


   // addOperation
    publicData.addOperation(operation)

publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
    if error == nil { // There is no error
        // PROBLEM .. this prints out all values ????
        print(results)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        })
    }
    else {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

//// The following / amended code works fine

```
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase

    // select all records
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "quizRecord", predicate: predicate)

    // get just one value only
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.desiredKeys = ["age"]


    // get query
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record : CKRecord) in
        // process record

        print(record)

    }


    // operation completed
    operation.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if error == nil {

                print("no errors")
                // code here

            } else {

                print("error description = \(error?.description)")
            }
        }
    }

        // addOperation
    publicData.addOperation(operation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple. You set the `desiredKeys` on the `CKQueryOperation` but you never actually use the operation. You instead use `performQuery` on the database.

If you to use the operation and limit the data to the specific keys, you need to add the operation to the database (using `addOperation:`) instead of calling `performQuery`. And of course you need to assign a block to the one or more of the `recordFetchedBlock` and `queryCompletionBlock` properties of the operation.

```
let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase

// select all records
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "quizRecord", predicate: predicate)

// get just one value only
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.desiredKeys = ["age"]

operation.recordFetchBlock = { (record : CKRecord) in
    // process record
}
operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor : CKQueryCursor!, error : NSError!) in
    // Query finished
}

// addOperation
publicData.addOperation(operation)
```

Comment: @maddy. Thanks for your help. So I've added the operation to the database  (above code edited) but I don't understand how I do this instead of calling performQuery ??

Comment: As I said, you need to assign a block to one or both of the `recordFetchedBlock` and `queryCompletionBlock` properties. It's in those blocks that you process the results. And DO NOT use both `addOperation` and `performQuery`. Only use one or the other.

Comment: @maddy. sorry I'm totally lost when you say use one or the other. Could you help with the code for performing a Query with desiredKeys:

Comment: @pete See the updated answer. You need to fill in the appropriate code to process each record and any code you want when the query is finished.

Comment: @maddy - thanks for your help and amended code.  I had to make a few changes on recordFetchedBlock and the queryCompletionBlock but all is working fine. Thanks again (see working code edited above)

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote helpful answers.